# @ActiveProfiles in meta annotation and on test class not working

Tags: spring, junit, annotations, spring-annotations, spring-test

I created a meta annotation @EmbeddedMongoDBUnitTest that activates two profiles to be used in spring based unit tests. The basic setup works:

```java
@Documented
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ActiveProfiles({"embeddedMongoDB", "embeddedMongoDBUnitTest"})
public @interface EmbeddedMongoDBUnitTest {
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EmbeddedMongoDBUnitTest
@ContextConfiguration(...)
public class WorkingTest {
    ...
}
```

Now when trying to activate another profile with another @ActiveProfiles annotation on the test class itself, the profiles in @EmbeddedMongoDBUnitTest aren't activated anymore:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EmbeddedMongoDBUnitTest
@ActiveProfiles({"h2IntegrationTests"})
@ContextConfiguration(...)
public class NotWorkingTest {
    ...
}
```

Is there a reason why this is not working or is this a bug in the spring test code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a bug: this is by design.

The reason this does not work is that this form of configuration is simply not supported by Spring.

The algorithm that the Spring Framework uses when searching for an annotation stops once it has found the first occurrence of the sought annotation. Thus, in your example, the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation on `NotWorkingTest` effectively shadows the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation on your composed `@EmbeddedMongoDBUnitTest` annotation.

Please note that these are the general semantics for annotations in the core Spring Framework. In other words, the behavior you are experiencing is not specific to the `spring-test` module.

Having said that, profiles declared via `@ActiveProfiles` are in fact *inherited* within a test class hierarchy (unless you set the `inheritProfiles` flag to `false`). But don't confuse class hierarchies with annotation hierarchies: Java supports inheritance for interfaces and classes but not for annotations.

Hope this clarifies things!

Sam (component lead for the `spring-test` module)

Comment: Thanks for the exploration Sam. If this is not a bug, I'm questioning the design here. It may be true that the spring framework only searches for the first Annotation, but in this case one really expects that all @ActiveProfiles annotations are picked up, esp. if it's supported with class inheritance.

Comment: James, feel free to create a JIRA issue to request such a feature at http://jira.spring.io, and we will consider it.

Comment: @SamBrannen Is there any JIRA ticket regarding this issue? I didn't manage to find it yet

Comment: It could be a good time to say that since Spring 4 this has changed and @ActiveProfiles is a meta-annotation

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles` is not a meta-annotation per se. It's an annotation which _can_ be used as a meta-annotation since Spring 4. However, the OP was obviously already using Spring 4+, since his `@EmbeddedMongoDBUnitTest` worked stand-alone.

Comment: @Anton, I don't think anybody ever created a JIRA issue for this topic.

Comment: I opened an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23299

Comment: The upcomming Spring Framework 5.2 will include this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23299#issuecomment-515765514

Comment: Issue for composable `@ActiveProfiles` is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26145