# Can @ContextConfiguration in a custom annotation be merged?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I am working on custom Spring Boot starters. In a test starter what I wanted do to is to implement a composed annotation, which would add additional `@Configuration` classes to the `ApplicationContext` (and possibly use this annotation in a `TestExecutionListener`). ex:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AdditionalTestConfiguration.class)
public @interface ComposedAnnotation {
}
```

And use that in my Spring Boot integration test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
@ComposedAnnotation
public class SomeTest {
}
```

No inheritance is involved. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. I doubt it's a Spring Boot thing, rather Spring testing framework itself.

Is there any way I can achieve expected result?

Comment: FYI: `@ContextConfiguration(AdditionalTestConfiguration.class)` does not compile. The `value` attribute in `@ContextConfiguration` is a `String[]` of locations for XML files or Groovy scripts.

Comment: Thanks, for the catch. I was typing it from the top of my head. Corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: this is not an issue with Spring Boot. But it's also not an issue with `spring-test`.

Rather, it's the intended behavior of Spring in general. For details, check out my answer to this question: [@ActiveProfiles in meta annotation and on test class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176038/activeprofiles-in-meta-annotation-and-on-test-class-not-working)

In summary, you cannot achieve this with two `@ContextConfiguration` annotations declared on an individual test class (either directly or as meta-annotations).

However, I just came up with a *trick* that will allow you to achieve this. Specifically, you can create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` (ACI) that registers one or more `@Configuration` classes. In your composed annotation, you can then register this ACI to register the *always present `@Configuration` classes*. And when the composed annotation is actually used, it can declare additional `@Configuration` classes like normal.

I just submitted a working example in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/18e9699a2b31204feb1ae76a3e4b19cae7666236).

Basically, the code would look something like this:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, initializers = FooConfigInitializer.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ComposedContextConfiguration {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ContextConfiguration.class, attribute = "classes")
    Class<?>[] value() default {};
}
```

```java
public class FooConfigInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        new AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader(applicationContext).register(FooConfig.class);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComposedContextConfiguration(BarConfig.class)
public class InitializerConfiguredViaMetaAnnotationTests { /* ... */ }
```

Your `ApplicationContext` will then be loaded from `FooConfig` and `BarConfig`.

The above examples obviously do not use Spring Boot, but the same principles should also be applicable to `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and sharing possible workaround. I don't think it will fit my needs though.
What I want to achieve is to have a way to introduce mocked (*optional*) implementations of some features. i.e. I use Java 8 Clock bean for getting datetime: ZonedDateTime.now(clock). In some of my ITs i want to use FixedClock with specific value. I would like to use dedicated annotation (with parameters) to do that (setting up @Primary bean overriding the default). I'd tried programatically add primary beans in TestExecutionListeners , but I had issues with that.
Any suggestions on that?