# Test configuration annotations in separate annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-test

I have a problem with spring annotations. All I want to do is grab whole necessary test annotations to one annotation with common config and I get null pointer exception when Spring Context starts (cannot autowire beans) but when I use those annotations separately in every test class everything works fine.

Here is an example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JPAConfig.class, AOPConfiguration.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public @interface MyTestAnnotations {
}
```

And test case that I want to use configuration from @MyTestAnnotations

```
@MyTestAnnotations
public class AspectTest {

   @Autowired
   PagingAndSortingBookRepository pagingAndSortingRepo;
   @Autowired
   SmartLoggerAspect smartLoggerAspect;

   JoinPoint joinPoint;
   // other methods

    @Test
    public void pagingTest(){
           // line below throws nullPointerException
           pagingAndSortingRepo.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by the design you can not combine @ContextConfiguration with custom annotation. [see the nice explanation provided sam branan why it would not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26183692/410677)

you should be able to use something like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public @interface MyTestAnnotations {
}

@MyTestAnnotations
public abstract class AbstractBaseTests
{
}


@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JPAConfig.class, AOPConfiguration.class })
public class MyTest extends AbstractBaseTests {
  }
```

Comment: It helps when I move @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) from @MyTestAnnotations to AbstractBaseTest. Thans!

Comment: I don't know why this guy just make it happens there:
https://youtu.be/5tgkxGEvK4U?t=2228

Comment: @PrzemysławSienkiewicz yes. make me wonder bit as well. I am not sure about this whether it actually work. anyway thanks for sharing

Comment: Well, I'm "that guy", so let me explain... JUnit 4 does not support the use of `@RunWith` as a meta-annotation. So although Spring finds your annotations declared as meta-annotations, JUnit 4 does not find `@RunWith` unless it is directly declared on a class. That's why you can't use `@RunWith` as a meta-annotation.